# sql : join and group by

Tags: sql

Having 3 tables:

> movie(id, title, yr, score, votes,
>   director) actor(id, name)
>   casting(movieid, actorid, ord)
>
> Q:Which were the busiest years for
>   'John Travolta'. Show the number of
>   movies he made for each year.

A: My try is syntactically worng. why ?

```
select yr, count(*)
from 

(actor join casting
on (actor.id = casting.actorid)

join 
on (movie.id = casting.movieid)

group by yr 
having actor.name='John Travolta'
```

Comment: select yr, count(*) from actor join casting on (actor.id = casting.actorid) join movie on (movie.id = casting.movieid) group by yr having actor.name='John Travolta'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You are missing the second table name after `join`
- use `where` not `having`

Try this:

```
select yr, count(*)
from actor
join casting on actor.id = casting.actorid
join movie on movie.id = casting.movieid -- you were missing table name "movie"
where actor.name='John Travolta' -- "where", not "having"
group by yr
```

Also note the consistent formatting I used. If you use a good format, it's easier to find syntax errors

FYI, `having` is used for aggregate functions, eg `having count(*) > 3`

Comment: Why "where" instead of "having"? I don't wnat to filter the whole table just one group out of all the groups. no?

Comment: @user311130: You do want to filter the whole table. In your words: ***"Show the number of movies he made"*** where *"he"* means John Travolta. So, you really only care for data regarding John Travolta and no one else.

Comment: Tried you solution. It worked. But what if I want to select the rows with the highest count (there are two rows in the first place) ?

Comment: Add `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` in the end of the query to show the most busy years first.

Comment: ypercube, I undertand what you said. But why would my groupong be wrong ?

Comment: ypercube, "show the most busy years first" - I want to show them only not just first

Comment: Well, @Bohemian can add that too, in his answer. You'll need to include his query (as a subquery) in an outer one and use `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `(` `)` from around the table name and add `movie` to your second join.

```
select yr, count(*)
from actor join
    casting on actor.id = casting.actorid join
    movie on movie.id = casting.movieid
group by yr
having actor.name='John Travolta'
```

**EDIT:**

You need to switch your `having` to a `where` because havings are use for aggregate functions in conjunctions with your `group by`.

```
select yr, count(*)
from actor join
    casting on actor.id = casting.actorid join
    movie on movie.id = casting.movieid
where actor.name = 'John Travolta'
group by yr
```

Comment: This misses the real issue, aka the having clause which will yield a field not found error.

Answer (score 0):

To join u have to specify table ure joining, should be

```
join  movie
 on movie.id = casting.movieid
```